# aws-cli (v2) hangs command line with --filters options

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, terminal, aws-cli

If I run this command using aws v2:

```
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --filters '[{"Name":"group-name","Values":["launch-wizard-1"]}]'
```

Then the terminals hangs - there's a long list of stuff displayed (expected), however the commande doesn't return per se. I cannot enter new commands and can only move the cursor to the end:

[image]

I need to ctrl+c to get the prompt back. The issue is that when chaining commands, I cannot use the output of that command - e.g. the list of commands gets hung on that one and the rest doesn't execute.

Same thing happens when I run `aws ec2 run-instance (...) --tag-specifications 'ResourceType=instance,Tags=[{Key=Name,Value=TESTCICD}]'`

I want to do other things after creating the instance, but get hung on that...

Any way to fix this bug/issue? I don't want to just silence the output, as I might want to read the output & extract values from for later instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Okay simple answer turns out - the cli-pager is the culprit. THere's a global flag to turn it off, like so:

```
aws --no-cli-pager ec2 describe-security-groups --filters '[{"Name":"group-name","Values":["launch-wizard-1"]}]'
```

EDIT: see also John's comment to turn it off globally (linux). edit `~/.aws/config` and add `cli_pager=`, which will turn off/default to "false".

Comment: Yes. I like turning off the pager globally by inserting `cli_pager=` into the config file. It's more a pain than a benefit! See: [Using AWS CLI pagination options - AWS Command Line Interface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-pagination.html)